# 5-pin DIN socket advertised as MIDI, not the same as on my MIDI gear

Tags: cables, plug, midi, dimensions

I bought a 180-degree 5-pin DIN chassis-mount socket dirt-cheap for a project, but I saw that it looks quite different from the MIDI outs on my MIDI gear; I did some research but couldn't find any info on MIDI plugs being any kind of specialized DIN shape, just 5-pin 180-degree DIN.
I just ordered another chassis-mount socket from UK, advertised on their site specifically as being for MIDI, but it's the same as the cheap one I got before, and doesn't appear to be the same as on my gear. I currently don't own a cable, so my own tests are pending. But when they say MIDI is 180-degree 5-pin DIN, is it really exactly the same or is there some other specification that needs to be made between different layouts of 180-degree 5-pin DIN? Diameter of the semicircle? Size and shape of the aligning nub?
I can easily believe no one has ever actually ordered this product and tried to use it since the UK online store has been running! What I can't believe is that this information doesn't exist anywhere within Google's reach. It's out there somewhere.

Comment: Google "midi connector dimensions"

Comment: I've seen two types - one larger than the other.

Comment: @Andyaka Mini-DIN is not the same as DIN, and would be advertized as such.

Comment: @CL. It may be advertised as such but the question I have is did the Op notice that subtlety?

Comment: Add a photo of both connector types.

Comment: @EMFields I did that and sifted through several pages of results without coming across that information. If all questions could be easily answered with Google, stackexchange would not exist.

Comment: It's actually not so easy for a layman like myself to precisely measure. I attempted a rubbing, but it's recessed in there and it's harder than it looks.

Comment: I don't get the reason for the :"If all questions... " attitude, and a photo of your gear showing the connectors and some kind of dimensional reference would help, as would knowing what MIDI gear you're  running.

Comment: @EMFields It's a fact. I googled "MIDI connector dimensions" and all I could find anywhere is that it is a 5-pin 180-degree DIN, which tells me that you didn't actually try Googling it before telling me to do so. On stackexchange my question was answered within a day. The question also did not pertain to the connector I bought. I also realized that the one I bought does not resemble the one advertised on the Hobbytronics site, which caused a delay in posting a photo. Anyway, the question was about the DIN standard and someone answered it on stackexchange, not Google.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for the info. I did not know about mini-DIN. As far as advertising, it was most definitely advertised as MIDI, and I believe it said "DIN", not "mini-DIN".

Answer (score 3):

"DIN" is the name of the German standardization body; all the relevant dimensions are exactly specified in DIN 41524, or nowadays [IEC 60130-9](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/837).

The cable's connector has five simple pins:
[image: MIDI connector]

There are different ways of aligning the springs that hold these pins:
[image: MIDI jack]
[image: MIDI jack]

However, what matters are the positions of the actual pins and holes, and those are always the same:
[image: MIDI connector dimensions]

Comment: Thanks for the direct answer! May I ask if you found this info online, and where? Or do you know from your experience?
So, when I pick up that cable next week, if it doesn't go into the holes of the panel mount connector I bought, I can complain to Hobbytronics UK.

Comment: This is just from various connector datasheets, found via Google.

Answer (score 1):

Easily found through Google, the current MIDI spec's [**are available here:**](https://www.midi.org/specifications/item/midi-din-electrical-specification) 
of which page 3, excerpted below, describes the connectors:

[image]

Following up on their Switchcraft link [**leads to:**](http://www.switchcraft.com/Category.aspx?Parent=800)

Where you'll surely find what you need.

Comment: Thank you, and yes, I read that already, but this does not answer the question of whether all 5-pin 180-degree DIN connectors have the same dimensions - i.e., the distances between the pins, the radius of the circle in which they are positioned, etc. I asked CL where he/she got the info, still waiting to see.

Comment: In fact, most stackexchange answers could probably also be found by following links from links from Google results, sifting through official standards documents, etc., but I still think stackexchange has a place that Google can't take in the exchange of information.

Comment: @ChuckkHubbard: Part 1. If you're still waiting, it appears you missed  CL's reply of 11 April, where he cites his source as DIN itself, with his reference being: "DIN 41524, or nowadays IEC 60130-9." If you want to pay to download the document it should give you everything you need.  If you choose not to, [Switchcraft's site](http://www.switchcraft.com/productsummary.aspx?Parent=592) can get you started by giving you the bolt circle for the 180\$\degree\$ 5 pin female.  Part 2 follows...

Comment: @ChuckkHubbard: Part 3: On top of all of that, you haven't stated  what relationship exists  between the [your] MIDI equipment you made allusion to and your "project", nor have you responded to requests  asking for photos of your equipment from which dimensional assessments might be made in order to help you on your way.  Instead, you seem to take every opportunity to demur, slight, and prolong your stay. Why>

Comment: @ChuckkHubbard : Part 2. Since the male will have to plug into it, all you'll really have to do once you decide what it is you want to plug into what, is to figure out the diameter of the male pins. But, since that's all been figure out beforehand, it's moot.

Comment: I replied to both CL's answer and the request for photos. I do not have access to a decent digital camera, and the socket I bought does not match the photo on the site that sold it to me. Thanks for your help. I do not intend to demur and slight; I just don't get much use out of the #1 internet non-answer of "Check Google". To me, that is a slight. Anyone who uses Google regularly for real problems knows that it can take days or weeks to find the answers to some questions. In many cases, you find endless links to other people asking the same questions and no answer.

Comment: Your reply to CL's answer - since he identified his source as the relevant DIN spec - seems to be oriented toward assigning blame for a shopping error you  committed - on your own - to anyone else but you. Your negative reply to  the request for a photo of your equipment adds fuel to the fire that, more to the point, after all of this tete-a-tete  you still haven't defined what it is you're trying to do and how - as requested - it relates to the MIDI stuff you say you have on hand. As a consequence, I'm going to vote to shut your question down unless you can show why you're not just  shopping.

Comment: I asked CL how he or she found that info so that I know where to look next time. Regarding the question, I happen to think there's a chance of other people wondering the same thing, but either way, I got the answer I was looking for.